# What would cause Dojo in later versions of ArcGIS Javascript (v3.12) from working in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, error, dojo, internet-explorer

On my testing machine I experience no problems with using

http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/featuretable/

but if I run the same example on my client's machine I get "'require' is undefined".

I also experience the same issue with all of their 3.12 examples. Only 3.1 examples seem to work on my client's machine.

Update: It also works just fine in FF and Chrome on client machine

Comment: *require* missing is definitely linked to Dojo. Did you install the API locally?

Comment: nope, it's getting it all from the web.

Comment: Have you tried it using different browsers? Your client's browser might be blocking Dojo for some reason.

Comment: it works fine in FF and Chrome. Is there something I can do to check if IE is blocking dojo in some way?

Comment: So it only happens in IE? Depending on what version it is you can hit F12 and open the developer tools. You should also probably search the internet about Dojo not working in that version of IE.

Comment: I can go in the dev tools but it just gets to the portion of code regarding require and says "SCRIPT5009: 'require' is undefined"

Comment: Seems to be a very specific 'Dojo in IE issue'. You might also want to ask or search on Stack Overflow, as I think this might not necessarily be linked to the ArcGIS JS API. Are you using the latest version of IE? Have you cleared history/caches?

Comment: Maybe you are running in compatibility mode? From release notes: "Also please note that even if IE6 and 7 code paths have not been removed, Dojo 1.10 is removing official support for those browsers."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause:

I had to enable "Active Scripting" in Tool -> Internet Options -> Security Tab -> Custom Level

I also had to run-as-administrator IE to be able to change those settings.

I'm surprised that there wasn't an issue when running version 3.1 of ESRI's API.